# Docker process killed with cryptic `Killed` message

Tags: python, macos, docker, docker-machine

Running a python script in a docker container and everything seems to be running smoothly, seeing some STDOUT messages, about 5 minutes in I get a `Killed` message with no further explanation and the process stops. Querying a db so could be a disk space issue, could be OOM issue. I'm not sure but I have no idea where to find logs about this kill message so I can get to the root of this problem. Any ideas where these logs are?

Running docker-machine on Mac OSX.

That's really all the message says!

```
root@c7b800e0f276:/opt/mymodule# python
Python 2.7.13 (default, May  1 2017, 22:44:36)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mymodule import model
>>> model.run('2017-04-01')
INFO:Deleting from input table.
INFO:Inserting into input table.
INFO:Querying input table for chunk.
Killed
root@c7b800e0f276:/opt/mymodule# exit
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the stdout 'killed' message. As for the logs, you check the [Configure logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) documentation.

Comment: I swear thats all I get as a message! Posted it above anyways @vmg

Comment: Killed usually means SIGKILL, OOM is the most common reason. In Linux `dmesg` would show you if this is the case, not sure about OSX.

Answer (score 151):

*Docker for Mac* limits the resource available to **2GB** by default! This is too low for the app that I run. The solution is to increase the memory limit to **8GB**, or however much your app needs.

(I am having similar issue albeit using a JVM application, not Python, and reached here by Google searching. From the deleted answer by [@sergiu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417159/docker-process-killed-with-cryptic-killed-message/45989663#45989663) I am able to figure out the issue.)

[Get started with Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#advanced) says:

[image: Advanced]

> Advanced settings are:
>
> **CPUs**: By default, Docker for Mac is set to use half the number of processors available on the host machine. To increase processing power, set this to a higher number; to decrease, lower the number.
>
> **Memory**: By default, Docker for Mac is set to use `2` GB runtime memory, allocated from the total available memory on your Mac. To increase RAM, set this to a higher number; to decrease it, lower the number.
>
> **Swap**: Configure swap file size as needed. The default is 1 GB.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. The message "Killed" is so non helpful, that it's basically a bug in docker.

Comment: Being "out of memory" and thus being killed doesn't apply to MacOS only, of course! The same can be checked and configured on other docker hosts like Unix and Windows but also on cloud services like Kubernetes, OpenShift, AWS, GCP, Azure ...

Answer (score 16):

With Docker for Mac, you can get into the host VM namespace with:

```
docker run --net=host --ipc=host --uts=host --pid=host -it --security-opt=seccomp=unconfined --privileged --rm -v /:/host alpine /bin/sh
```

Then run `chroot /host` to change root to the host mount. Now, you can use utilities like `dmesg` to check for any OOM message (like the comments to your question suggest).

Comment: Using just `--privileged` flag already let me use the `dmesg` utility.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because your application is consuming all the RAM available.
You can monitor the RAM consumption and increase it.

This worked for me