# Getting error: unexpected "js-yaml.js" output while parsing config from mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, yaml

A mongodb container is successfully created based on below docker-compose configuration:

```
mongodb:
    build: ./mongodb
    container_name: iboorse_mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb/001_init-mongo.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001_init-mongo.sh
      - ./mongodb/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - ${MONGO_EXPOSED_PORT}:27017
```

after some time, some data was stored in the DB but got the below error. the container is being terminated immediately after it starts. (so I don't have enough time to connect to the container and investigate the problem).

> error: unexpected "js-yaml.js" output while parsing config

mongodb.conf:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
# systemLog:
#   destination: file
#   logAppend: true
#   path: /data/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
  # bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  authorization: 'enabled'

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you get anywhere in resolving it? Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't find the root of the issue, unfortunately.
I ended up applying a daily backup strategy and doing less docker restart on the MongoDB container to prevent losing data.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Docker Compose here, but Kubernetes. I ran into the exact same issue. In a long and tedious debugging session, I figured out that the script [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) uses `mongosh` to load the script `/js-yaml.js`, that further converts your MongoDB YAML configuration into JSON. Loading that script failed and caused `mongosh` crash with a non-meaningful "`Killed`" message.

The cause of that crash is usually [insufficient resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44417159/docker-process-killed-with-cryptic-killed-message). In my case, I had explicitely limited the container's memory to only 128Mi which had been far from enough. I increased it to 512Mi and the error was gone.

Solution (for me): Check your [memory limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory) and increase them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (upgrade mongo in docker from 5.0.x to 6.0.x), use `-f` instead of `--config` will resolve it.